# How do I make non-rectangular slices in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, slices

I bought this:

[image]
http://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?id=297036404&src=id

And now I need to export each sign as an individual file (PNG or JPG). If there was more distance between the individual signs, I'd be able to use the Slice tool, creating square/rectangular slices. Give how the signs are placed, **how do I create non-rectangular slices that will allow me to export in one shot, with an individual file generated for each sign?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with slices. [Slices](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/slices-image-maps.html) are designed to output HTML tables so they are only rectangular.

There aren't that many signs anyway so I would separate them manually, it shouldn't take more than a minute or two.

Instead of using slices though, I would put each sign on its own artboard so you can easily export to JPG or PNG.

1. Manually separate the signs
2. **Group** (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) each sign so they are all in their own group. (If they aren't already)
3. **Select All** (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) then from the Layers panel dropdown select **'Release to Layers (Sequence)'** (if each sign is already on its own layer you can skip this step.)
4. Use [this script](https://github.com/michaelchaize/appliness/blob/master/Illustrator-create-artboards/CreateArtboardsLayers.jsx) or [this script](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4757712#4757712) to create a new artboard for each of your new layers.
5. **File > Export...** and check **'Use Artboards'**

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't quite succeed at using those scripts, but your answer pointed me to the idea of using Artboards, so I did that. I added tons of artboards, copied every sign onto its own artboard (named so that I knew which row/column combination they came from, in the legend/overview), and then scaled each sign up 900% in its artboard. That way I export as you described, and if people need smaller versions of those graphics, I just show them how to use Windows Image Resizer Power Toy to scale them back down. Not the most elegant solution, but it worked given deadline. Thx 4 the help!

Comment: Did I mention I'm not a graphic designer? :o)

Comment: No problem. Not sure if scaling to 900% is the most elegant solution but if it works, it works :)